# Entity Framework objects being duplicated in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework (code first) for the first time and I have a little problem.

I have a class called Taxi & one called Driver

Taxi has a reference to the Driver, you can see both classed below

```
  public partial class Taxi
    {
        public Taxi()
        {
        }

        public int TaxiId { get; set; }
        public Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public Color Colour { get; set; }
        public string NumPlate { get; set; }
        public int MaxPassengers { get; set; }
}


    public partial class Driver
    {
        public Driver()
        {

        }

        public int DriverId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinedFirm { get; set; }
}
```

And I am saving the changed Taxi like this:

```
 using (var db = new DataModel())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            db.Taxis
                .Where(x => x.TaxiId == CurrenltySelectedTaxi.TaxiId)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x =>
                {
                    x.Make = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Make;
                    x.Model = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Model;
                    x.NumPlate = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.NumPlate;
                    x.Colour = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Colour;
                    x.MaxPassengers = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.MaxPassengers;
                    x.Driver = CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Driver;
                });

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

My problem is that the Driver gets duplicated the in database every time I save a taxi.

You can see the database here:
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction, 
Thanks

EDIT:
The drivers are in a combo box and are selected like this

```
private void cmbTaxiDriver_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new DataModel())
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Driver listSelected = (Driver) cmbTaxiDriver.SelectedItem;
        CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Driver = db.Drivers.Where(x => x.DriverId == listSelected.DriverId).ToArray()[0];
    }
}
```

And the combo box is populated like this:

```
        listDrivers.Items.AddRange(db.Drivers.ToArray());
```

Comment: please include additional code, like how `CurrenltySelectedTaxi` is selected.

Comment: also, I am going to assume there should only be one instance of `TaxiId` in your `db.Taxis`, if this is true, then do `db.Taxis.First(x => x.TaxiId == CurrenltySelectedTaxi.TaxiId)` then assign the properties. (assuming that the taxi id already exists, use FirstOrDefault if it may not exist)

Comment: Added how the Driver is selected. CurrentlySelectedTaxi is select is the same way just from another place

Comment: Could it be that your event `SelectIndexChanged` is called twice?

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference if it was called twice, as it makes NO changes to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my issue is because i followed the tutorial on MSDN that says to recreate your context EVERYTIME you use it. Although this 'may' be good practice, in this instance it caused the problem.

If I make one context for the entire class it works as expected/

Comment: Yes, but that leaves the connection to the database open, introducing other possible issues.  What you want to do is ensure your context knows how to deal with the items you give it by setting the proper state for the entity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can possibly find based on the content you have provided is that `CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Driver` is a detached or new driver.  Be careful to ensure that the object pointed to by `CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Driver` is an attached driver record.

An option you can do to help determine the status of that record is to put a breakpoint on that line and then look at the DbEntry record status.

Comment: How can I check this?   I populate the combo box like this `  listDrivers.Items.AddRange(db.Drivers.ToArray());` and select it like ` using (var db = new DataModel())
            {
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                Driver listSelected = (Driver) cmbTaxiDriver.SelectedItem;
                CurrenltySelectedTaxi.Driver = db.Drivers.Where(x => x.DriverId == listSelected.DriverId).ToArray()[0];
            }`

Comment: Don't add the entire record to the list and rely on the ToString() ... also ... do not keep your db context around very long ... only instantiate the db content when you are processing the transactions.  Otherwise, load the lists/comboboxes with ID's and Titles ... assign the x.Driver directly to an object in a DbSet ... or stop using the navigation property and assign the DriverID column instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your design doesn't create a relationship between Taxi and Driver that's going to translate to a database.  Try something like this:

```
public partial class Taxi
    {
        public Taxi()
        {
        }
        public int TaxiId { get; set; }
        public int DriverId {get; set; }
        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public Color Colour { get; set; }
        public string NumPlate { get; set; }
        public int MaxPassengers { get; set; }
}
```

You may also want to add the following to the Driver object:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Taxi> Taxis { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is what I had originally and I removed it because of the issue

Comment: Just tested again with public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }, I stepped through and DriverID = 2 after the db.SaveChanges() it changes to the next in the list(in this case 10, next test 11)

Comment: Are you still setting a value for the Driver property?  Because that shouldn't be necessary (and may even be the problem) - the important thing is to set the DriverId property to the correct value.

Comment: Yes I set the Driver, but its correct up until db.SaveChanges() it changes INSIDE that function

Comment: Right, so DON'T set the Driver property.  Just the DriverId.  Or if you absolutely must set the driver property, make sure you tag it as being updated, because it sounds like EF is defaulting to it being a new object.

Comment: You're using an existing object you pulled from the context with one instance of the db, but inserting it in a different instance.  There's no way EF sees that as an existing object.

Comment: Yes @Dave you are correct :) I already noticed this 2 twos ago. It wont let me accept the answer yet though